# python parsing xml with ElementTree doesn't give interested result

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sample>
    <text>My name is <b>Wrufesh</b>. What is yours?</text>
</sample>
```

I have a python code like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print child.text()
```

I only get

```
'My name is' as an output.
```

I want to get

```
'My name is <b>Wrufesh</b>. What is yours?' as an output.
```

What can I do?

Comment: try ```child.html()```

Comment: Element object has no attribute html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your desired output using using `ElementTree.tostringlist()`:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.parse('sample.xml').getroot()
>>> l = ET.tostringlist(root.find('text'))
>>> l
['<text', '>', 'My name is ', '<b', '>', 'Wrufesh', '</b>', '. What is yours?', '</text>', '\n']
>>> ''.join(l[2:-2])
'My name is <b>Wrufesh</b>. What is yours?'
```

I wonder though how practical this is going to be for generic use.

Comment: for my xml file it is working coz every text element has equal number of attribute. It wont be generic when i have variable number of attribute in text element. In that case range to join list should be calculated by analysing start and closeing tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't think treating tag in xml as a string is right. You can access the text part of xml like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*- 

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
text = root[0]
for i in text.itertext():
    print i

# As you can see, `<b>` and `</b>` is a pair of tags but not strings.
print text._children
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pre-processing the xml file to wrap elements under `<text>` element in [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp). You should be able to read the values without a problem afterwards.

```
<text><![CDATA[<My name is <b>Wrufesh</b>. What is yours?]]></text>
```

Comment: If OP could pre-process the file to wrap the required text, he might as well extract the required text then and there without taking the additional step of parsing and extracting the data in ElementTree.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. What I am suggesting is if the value placed inside text element can be wrapped in CDATA, like at generation time then he should consider that. On a separate note utar far simpler to do a global replace of <text> with <text>! <[CDATA[